# Prevent jshint from reporting that a variable is unused for specific local variables?

Tags: javascript, jshint

When running jshint on several of my javascript files, I get warnings like this:

```
file.js: line X, col 93, 'fromParams' is defined but never used.
file.js: line X, col 72, 'toParams' is defined but never used.
file.js: line X, col 63, 'toState' is defined but never used.
file.js: line X, col 56, 'event' is defined but never used.
```

For something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // ... some code that doesn't use event, toState, toParams, or fromParams...
});
```

This comes up very often for callbacks of one sort or another -- the callback function requires a certain number of parameters, but my code in the function doesn't use all of the parameters, so jshint complains about them. But the parameters need to be there!

There's supposed to be ways of disabling this warning in certain sections of code like this:

```
/*jshint -W098 */
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
/*jshint +W098 */
```

But it doesn't work due to a bug in jshint, see [this open issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1140).

It's also possible to disable this warning for entire functions like so:

```
/* jshint unused:false */
```

...but this is unacceptable, because it would suppress the warning for *all* unused variables in the function, and I want to be notified about anything that's unused *except* for the function parameters I specifically know I'm not going to use.

Is there anyway for me to work around this? I'd very much like my code to not trigger any linter warnings, but as it stands, jshint will report several "defined but never used" warnings that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Add `/*jshint unused:false*/` in the scope of the (the first line inside the function) function should do it. You can't be specific to a particular variable, not that I know of. This will only be enforced in the function's scope.

Comment: If you don't need any of the parameters you can remove them... they don't need to be there,

Comment: I was going to add that. :) Another alternative (in some worst case where jshint is more important, but not necessarily, than your actual code) is to create `var`s inside the function and assign them with `arguments[n]`

Comment: @Xotic750 I did mention /* jshint unused: false */ in my original post, and why I'm not able to use it: it would suppress all warnings for that entire function, and I need to know if there are other unused variables aside from the unused parameters.

Comment: @BrianGlaz - I'm not keen to remove parameters like that. For one, I think it's pretty ugly and a flaw of javascript that you're allowed to do that, but that's just my opinion. But more practically, if I'm using the last parameter I'll need the other ones there.

Comment: Then I guess your out of luck and will need to add some code to use your unused variables just to keep jslint happy. Have a global scoped variable say `var jshintUnused` and then when you have an unused variable `jshintUnused = event` and so on, that should do what you want I believe.

Comment: @Xotic750 - Just gave your suggestion a try, but then jshint complains about the jshintUnused variable! I suppose I could use a global that isn't used for anything else that I tell jshint to ignore, or I could write a function that doesn't do anything and pass in the unused parameters as arguments. It's kind of ugly, but I don't think I have a lot of other options.

Comment: I posted an answer to demonstrate the use, jsHint does not complain for me. Never said it was pretty, it's a work around based on your opinions and requirement. :)

Comment: You can use `/* jshint unused:vars */` at the top of the function to suppress warnings about function parameters but still get warnings about other variables.

Comment: @vrmc That does exactly what I want. Please submit it as an answer and not a comment so I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `/* jshint unused:vars */` at the top of the function to suppress warnings about function parameters but still get warnings about other variables.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you based on your question and comments.

```
/*global console */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var jshintUnused;

    (function () {
        return;
    }(jshintUnused));

    function blah(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        jshintUnused = arg1;
        jshintUnused = arg2;
        console.log(arg3);
    }

    blah(null, null, 'Hello world');
}());
```

Now compare the above method against `/*jshint unused: false*/`

[jsHint unused](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#unused)

> In addition to that, this option will warn you about unused global
>   variables declared via the global directive.
>
> This can be set to vars to only check for variables, not function
>   parameters, or strict to check all variables and parameters. The
>   default (true) behavior is to allow unused parameters that are
>   followed by a used parameter.

```
/*global console */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var jshintUnused;

    (function () {
        return;
    }(jshintUnused));

    function blah(arg1, arg2, arg3, oops) {
        jshintUnused = arg1;
        jshintUnused = arg2;

        var hmm;

        console.log(arg3);
    }

    blah(null, null, 'Hello world');
}());
```

The above will know that `oops` and `hmm` shouldn't have been declared and you will get. `Warning: unused var: oops, hmm`

```
/*global console */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    function blah(arg1, arg2, arg3, oops) {
        /*jshint unused: false */
        var hmm;

        console.log(arg3);
    }

    blah(null, null, 'Hello world');
}());
```

In the above `jsHint` ignored the unused variable check for the entire function and you will get no warnings at all.

The method that I have demonstrated allows you to:

> Prevent jshint from reporting that a variable is unused for specific local variables?

The other suggestion that I made was to assign the parameters to be used to a variable local to the function using `arguments`.

```
/*global console */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    function blah() {
        var arg3 = arguments[2];

        console.log(arg3);
    }

    blah(null, null, 'Hello world');
}());
```

But this didn't seem to fit your requirements based on your comments.

> But the parameters need to be there!
>
> I'm not keen to remove parameters like that. For one, I think it's
>   pretty ugly and a flaw of javascript that you're allowed to do that,
>   but that's just my opinion. But more practically, if I'm using the
>   last parameter I'll need the other ones there.

Finally, `/*jshint unused: vars */` is suggested.

```
/*global console */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    function blah(arg1, arg2, arg3, oops) {
        /*jshint unused: vars */
        var hmm;

        console.log(arg3);
    }

    blah(null, null, 'Hello world');
}());
```

When I try this with the latest `jsHint` form the [git repo](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) then I get

```
Four unused variables
8   hmm
6   oops
6   arg2
6   arg1
```

Which was not what I expected, I would have expected.

```
Four unused variables
8   hmm
```

You can try all of these [online](http://jshint.com/) by pasting them directly into the the interface.

Comment: Thanks - your first method looks quite nice!  Would you be willing to dual-license it MIT or CC-BY?  (All of my contributions are dual-licensed CC-BY, so I'm not asking you to do anything I haven't myself :) .)

Answer (score 0):

ESLint offer better options for this use case which then allows you to not disable this very important rule (it saved me debugging time when refactoring some code)

1. by default, it won't throw warning for the first arguments if the last named argument is used (option `{ "args": "after-used" }`), which is useful as you won't always use all the received callback parameters
2. you can specify a parameter name pattern for those that can safely be ignored (option `{ "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }`

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

So if you have some code like

```
foo.bar(function (a, b, c, d) {
  var unusedLocal;

  console.log(c);
});
```

ESLint will only raise warnings for `"d"` and `"unsusedLocal"`

If you really want to leave the "d" parameter beacuse it is part of the standard callback signature and might be used later, the `"argsIgnorePattern"` comes to your help. And even better, it makes your whole code more explicit about intentionnaly unused variables

```
foo.bar(function (_a, _b, c, _d) {
  var unusedLocal;

  console.log(c);
});
```

This time, ESLint will only raise warnings for `"unsusedLocal"`
And you will know at first look which parameters are expected to be used or not in this code.